# Unknown Prop Warning

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an error when I work with children with props

`Unknown prop`close`on <h3> tag. Remove this prop from the element.`.

I created a parent block:

```
var Block = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {open: true}
  },

  close: function() {
    this.setState({open: false});
  },

  render: function() {
    var childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,      function(child) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
            close: this.close
        })
    }.bind(this));

    return (
        <div>
            {childrenWithProps}
        </div>
    )
 }
});
```

And use it in another component:

```
var Elm = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return (
        <Block>
            <h3>Hi</h3>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.props.close}>Close</button>
        </Block>
    )
}
});
```

I know it's because `<h3>` doesn't have `close`, but `button` has it.

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're mapping `React.Children` which internally iterates the `Block` component's children (including the `<h3>` tag) and then assigns the `close` property to it.

[Why you should pay attention to this warning.](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html)

But notice that neither `<h3>` nor `<button>` has the `close` property, what `<button>` has instead is the `this.prop.close` value passed as the `onClick` property.

What you can do then is to set some attribute to serve as a flag to your `Block` component so you can treat it like a "close element", let's call it `closeEmitter`:

**Block.render()**

```
var self = this;

var childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(function(child) {
  let extension = child.props.closeEmitter ? { onClick: self.close } : {}
  React.cloneElement(child, extension);
});

return <div>
  { childrenWithProps }
</div>
```

**Elm.js**

```
var Elm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <Block>
      <h3>Hi</h3>
      <button type="button" closeEmitter={ true }>Close</button>
    </Block>
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you. I'd like to create a Popup component which I can use everywhere. It can have a lot of children. And children can close it.

Comment: Then you should do as I said: define the `<button>` tag within the `Block` definition, just below `{ childrenWithProps }`

Comment: Yes, but `button` is just example. I can have an element which should close a Popup. For example, some link `Close popup` or after some action...

Answer (score 5):

Just rename your prop from "close" into "data-close". That's it.